# Overwriting values in a HashMap that are in an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Let's say I have a HashMap with String keys and Integer values:

```
map = {cat=1, kid=3, girl=3, adult=2, human=5, dog=2, boy=2}
```

I want to switch the keys and values by putting this information into another HashMap. I know that a HashMap cannot have duplicate keys, so I tried to put the information into a HashMap with the Integer for the keys that would map to a String ArrayList so that I could potentially have one Integer mapping to multiple Strings:

```
swap = {1=[cat], 2=[adult, dog, boy], 3=[kid, girl], 5=[human]}
```

I tried the following code:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> swap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

for (String x : map.keySet()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (i == map.get(x)) {
                list.add(x);
                swap.put(i, list);
            }
        }
    }
```

The only difference in my code is that I didn't hard code the number 5 into my index; I have a method that finds the highest integer value in the original HashMap and used that. I know it works correctly because I get the same output even if I hard code the 5 in there, I just didn't include it to save space.

My goal here is to be able to do this 'reversal' with any set of data, otherwise I could just hard code the value. The output I get from the above code is this:

```
swap = {1=[cat], 2=[boy], 3=[girl], 5=[human]}
```

As you can see, my problem is that the value ArrayList is only keeping the last String that was put into it, instead of collecting all of them. How can I make the ArrayList store each String, rather than just the last String?

Comment: There are several problems with your approach. First, `==` will only work for small numbers in `Integer`, not for numbers greater than 128 (or perhaps 255). Second, it's very inefficient - you loop over the entire range of numbers inside every step.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - offtopic of original question, but could you please elaborate why equal sign would work only on "small" Integer numbers?

Comment: @P.An he's talking about `Integer`'s internal caching for numbers (within the byte range I believe).

Comment: `==` shouldn't be used when comparing objects regardless, even `Integer`

Comment: @P.An - because Java maintains a cache of the most frequently used Integers in range [-127;128] by default.

Comment: @P.An It's a matter of identity vs. equality. `Integer`s are objects that wrap `int`s. There can be two `Integer`s with the same value, but they are different objects. Using `==` will compare if they are the same objects and you want to compare their values.

Comment: You've got some good answers here to your question as you asked it. But you should also consider that (unless you're trying to do this as an exercise in writing such data structures) there are existing implementations of what you're doing in libraries that you can use, e.g. [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), that may make your application easier to write.

Answer (score 23):

With Java 8, you can do the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("cat", 1);
map.put("kid", 3);
map.put("girl", 3);
map.put("adult", 2);
map.put("human", 5);
map.put("dog", 2);
map.put("boy", 2);

Map<Integer, List<String>> newMap = map.keySet()
                                       .stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map::get));

System.out.println(newMap);
```

The output will be:

`{1=[cat], 2=[adult, dog, boy], 3=[kid, girl], 5=[human]}`

Comment: You're welcome!  I apologize for using advanced code, but I recommend that you research streams in Java to fully understand this solution.

Comment: So this will only work for Map and List, not HashMap and ArrayList?

Comment: You can use a `HashMap`, and `ArrayList` because they implement the `Map` and `List` interfaces respectively.

Comment: Use the `EntrySet` rather than the key `Set` - in a `Map` keys and value are stored together in the `Entry` - you should never loop over the keys calling `get` each time; it's unperformant. Use a downstream `mapping` `Collection` to extract values from the entries.

Answer (score 6):

you are recreating the arrayList for every iteration and i can't figure out a way to do it with that logic, here is a good way though and without the need to check for the max integer:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    List<String> get = swap.get(value);
    if (get == null) {
        get = new ArrayList<>();
        swap.put(value, get);
    }
    get.add(key);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to iterate over the *key set* of the original map.

Also you have to asure that the List is present for any key in the target map:

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer>  inputEntry : map.entrySet())
  swap.computeIfAbsent(inputEntry.getValue(),()->new ArrayList<>()).add(inputEntry.getKey());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously not the best solution, but approaches the problem the same way you did by interchanging inner and outer loops as shown below.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("cat", 1);
    map.put("kid", 3);
    map.put("girl", 3);
    map.put("adult", 2);
    map.put("human", 5);
    map.put("dog", 2);
    map.put("boy", 2);

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> swap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    for (Integer value = 0; value <= 5; value++) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(key) == value) {
                list.add(key);
            }
        }
        if (map.containsValue(value)) {
            swap.put(value, list);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

> {1=[cat], 2=[adult, dog, boy], 3=[kid, girl], 5=[human]}

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad I know to learn about streams, but this is exactly what I was after; I was very curious to see where I went wrong.

Comment: This is quite bad. It assume that the range of values if known in advance, or must be calculated. I don't think that this approach is helpful as it teaches all the wrong things.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I've agreed in my post that this is not the best solution. My intention is to help the user identify the problem with his approach.

Comment: Exactly, I understand why this isn't a good approach, and another user showed me a much better one. I'm just starting out, so I was curious to see where I was wrong, so Beginner helped out a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Best way I can think of is using [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method on existing map and [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method on new map:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> swap = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> swap.computeIfAbsent(v, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(k));
```

As a side note, you can use the diamond operator `<>` to create your new map (there's no need to repeat the type of the key and value when invoking the map's constructor, as the compiler will infer them).

As a second side note, it's good practice to use interface types instead of concrete types, both for generic parameter types and for actual types. This is why I've used `List` and `Map` instead of `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, respectively.

Comment: Mutating collections from inside a `Stream` is an anti-pattern. Don't do this. That's what `Collector`s are for.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i'm not using any stream

Answer (score 1):

Using [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) like in [Jacob's answer](/questions/45014994/java-overwriting-values-in-a-hashmap-that-are-in-an-arrayliststring/#45015288) but with [`Map.entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) for better performance, as [suggested by Boris](/questions/45014994/java-overwriting-values-in-a-hashmap-that-are-in-an-arrayliststring/#comment77028124_45015288):

```
// import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*

Map<Integer, List<String>> swap = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, mapping(Entry::getKey, toList())));
```

This uses two more methods of [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html): [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

If it wasn't for these two helper functions, the solution could look like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> swap = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
            Entry::getValue,
            Collector.of(
                ArrayList::new,
                (list, e) -> {
                    list.add(e.getKey());
                },
                (left, right) -> { // only needed for parallel streams
                    left.addAll(right);
                    return left;
                }
            )
        )
    );
```

Or, using [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) instead of `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> swap = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        toMap(
            Entry::getValue,
            (e) -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(e.getKey())),
            (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            }
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams you override the values instrad of adding them to the already creared arraylist. Try this:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> swapedMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    Integer swappedKey = map.get(key);

    ArrayList<String> a = swapedMap.get(swappedKey);
    if (a == null) {
        a = new ArrayList<String>();
        swapedMap.put(swappedKey, a)
    }

    a.add(key);
}
```

I didn't have time to run it (sorry, don't have Java compiler now), but should be almost ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new `merge` method in java-8 from `Map`:

```
   Map<Integer, List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<>();

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(key);
        newMap.merge(value, values, (left, right) -> {
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
        });
    });
```